# System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute vs System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

i see that there are two version of ActionFilterAttribute class.
**System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute** and **System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute**

what is different?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [System.Web.Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) one is for Web API; the [System.Web.Mvc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) one is for previous MVC versions.

You can see from the source that the Web API version has several differences.

- It has `OnResultExecuting` and `OnResultExecuted` handlers (*"Called by the ASP.NET MVC framework before/after the action result executes."*)
- It can be executed [asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh943906%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
- It does *not* let you specify an order of execution

Comment: Actually, it's the Mvc filter that can have an order specified and Web API one can't

Answer (score 6):

System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute is intended for use with ASP.NET MVC.  System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute is intended for use with ASP.NET Web API.

MVC is web applications, Web API is HTTP services.

Their msdn pages are [System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and [System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)